# Change Value in XML File using xml2

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I got an .xml file that looks like this

```
<document>
<attribute1>false</attribute1>
<subjects>
    <subject>
        <population>Adult</population>
        <name>adult1</name>
    </subject>
</subjects>
</document>
```

and i want to change the value of `<name>` to "adult5".

I am using the xml2 package.
with `XMLFile <- read_xml(path_xml)` I raed the xml file and with `xml_children(xml_children(xml_children(XMLFile)[2])[[1]])[2]` i can access the node and R promts "adult1" on the console.

But if I try `xml_replace(xml_children(xml_children(xml_children(XMLFile)[2])[[1]])[2], "<name>adult5</name>")` it results in this `<<name>adult#005</name>/>`.

Probably a really stupid mistake that I am missing here ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select the node you want, then use `xml_text(node) <- "new text"` to overwrite the node. You don't need to put in tags, etc. - this is the whole point of using an xml package. A worked example for your case might be:

**File: my_xml.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <attribute1>false</attribute1>
  <subjects>
    <subject>
      <population>Adult</population>
      <name>adult1</name>
    </subject>
  </subjects>
</document>
```

Now in R:

```r
library(xml2)

XMLFile <- read_xml("my_xml.xml")

# Identify the node you want to change:
my_node <- xml_find_first(XMLFile, xpath = "//name")
xml_text(my_node)
#> [1] "adult1"

# Write to the node
xml_text(my_node) <- "adult5"

# Test the change has been made
xml_text(my_node)
#> [1] "adult5"

# Save the file
write_xml(XMLFile, "my_xml2.xml")
```

Now when we look at `my_xml2.xml`, our changes have been saved:

**File: my_xml2.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <attribute1>false</attribute1>
  <subjects>
    <subject>
      <population>Adult</population>
      <name>adult5</name>
    </subject>
  </subjects>
</document>
```